# uploading and saving a file in php

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file and save it in a folder. It prints: successful but the file is not in the destination folder. Do I give any sort of permissions? How do I give them? Also how do I specify destination folder path, i.e do I use \ or / ?

```php
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         echo "1";
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152) {
         echo "2";
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         echo "Sarang";
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/uploads".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>

<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "image" />
         <input type = "submit"/>

         <ul>
            <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  ?>
            <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  ?>
            <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['type'] ?>
         </ul>

      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's all in the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small issue I think. I believe this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/uploads".$file_name);
```

should be tweaked ever so slightly to:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/uploads/".$file_name);
```

because the filename (I would guess) does not have a leading forward slash.

Comment: ^... which is about all they're going to see. Another *"Go on take the money ♫ and run"* type of OP. Reminds you of a song? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/uploads".$file_name);
```

should be something like this:

```
$target_file = __DIR__ . "/uploads/" . $file_name; // don't forget the slash
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_file);
```

Destination path must be the full path on the server or relative to the current working directory.

A path like `/uploads/` will be interpreted as starting from root `/` directory if you use an UNIX OS, and if you don't have this path it won't save it.